# How to delete all records in table using CoolStorage?

Tags: c#, windows-phone, coolstorage

I use Vici CoolStorage for work with SQLite database in my Windows Phone application. How to delete all records in table?

Comment: take a look here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233823(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found my mistake. Correct query is CSDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(@"DELETE FROM TempTable") instead of the previously used CSDatabase.ExecuteNonQuery(@"DELETE FROM TABLE TempTable")